# ItemPreparedStatementSetter invalid in out parameter

Tags: oracle, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

In a spring batch application, I try to do an insert.

My query

```
public static final String = "insert into event(event_id, billingid, event_type, event_date, event_status, bill_date, is_mobile_payment, score, reason_id, created_date, created_by) values (event_seq.nextval, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
```

In a class who implements **ItemPreparedStatementSetter**, I have

```
@Override
public void setValues(SgaEvent event, PreparedStatement preparedStatement) throws SQLException {

    preparedStatement.setLong(1, event.getBillingid());
    preparedStatement.setByte(2, event.getEventType());
    preparedStatement.setDate(3, java.sql.Date.valueOf(event.getEventDate()));
    preparedStatement.setByte(4, (byte) EventStatus.SUCCESS.getId());
    preparedStatement.setDate(5, java.sql.Date.valueOf(event.getBillDate()));
    preparedStatement.setBoolean(6, true);
    preparedStatement.setByte(7, event.getScore());
    preparedStatement.setLong(8, event.getReasonId());
    preparedStatement.setTimestamp(9, java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()));
    preparedStatement.setString(10, "Automatic");
}
```

When I start application I get

```
SQL state [99999]; error code [17041]; Missing IN or OUT parameter at index :: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

There is issue related to your column name.

- Is date a column name?
- Why date column is reffered twice in column list?
- Check for the event table's column name and if `DATE` is column name then it is not allowed to use it as it is. You need to wrap it in double quotes. -- case sensitive
- Oracle recommend to not use the oracle reserved words as any object or column name.

Answer (score 0):

Could you narrow down by commenting each column attributes.

This is generic error of different set of failures. I am suspecting its related to Not Null values and is related Date or Time Stamp.

Please Try Two column setters Ist and add one by one column setter and verify which setter is failing and what is the value coming in that

preparedStatement.setLong(1, event.getBillingid());

preparedStatement.setByte(2, event.getEventType());